# React Native Navigator sample code from Facebook fails: type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

The related/similar questions were making simple mistakes (incorrect case for a property) etc. I'm using code that is lifted directly from the React Native site so it sure seems like it should work.

I'm trying to adapt the Navigator component in to a very simple existing app. I've started with the basic Navigator on the React Native pages: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-navigators

`./src/scene/myScene.jsx.js` (lifted directly from the tutorial):

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class MyScene extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Current Scene: {this.props.title}</Text>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onForward}>
          <Text>Tap me to load the next scene</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onBack}>
          <Text>Tap me to go back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

MyScene.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onForward: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onBack: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

`index.ios.js` (practically identical to the sample code):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native'; 
import {MyScene} from './src/scene/myScene.jsx.js'

export default class kisharNine extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ title: 'My Initial Scene', index: 0 }}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
          <MyScene
            title={route.title}

            // Function to call when a new scene should be displayed
            onForward={() => {
              const nextIndex = route.index + 1;
              navigator.push({
                title: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
                index: nextIndex,
              });
            }}

            // Function to call to go back to the previous scene
            onBack={() => {
              if (route.index > 0) {
                navigator.pop();
              }
            }}
          />
        }
      />
    )
  }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('kisharNine', () => kisharNine);
```

Error stack:

```
type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite 
components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Navigator`.

instantiateReactComponent
    instantiateReactComponent.js:77
instantiateChild
    ReactChildReconciler.js:56
<unknown>
    ReactChildReconciler.js:88
traverseAllChildrenImpl
    traverseAllChildren.js:83
```

The only difference that I can see is the constructor. Removing that made no difference. Is this possibly a bug in the example code?

Comment: try adding this prop: ref={this._setNavigator}, where _setNavigator is defined as   _setNavigator(navigatorInstance) {
    if (_navigator == undefined || _navigator == null) {
      _navigator = navigatorInstance;
    }
  }
Let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think is import {MyScene} from './src/scene/myScene.jsx.js', since you're doing export default it should be : import MyScene from './src/scene/myScene.jsx.js'

Comment: Also, you can just call your files .js, don't need to use .jsx.

Comment: .jsx helps with some beautifiers -- if they don't see jsx in the file name they will screw up the reformatting

Comment: I see I think -- since I'm using `export default` I don't need to destructure the object that's coming back, is that right? If I was exporting several objects/classes I would need to use the brace notation, right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You will only export default if your only exporting one thing. If you need to export multiple things then you will drop the 'default' part and will have to use the braces when importing.

Comment: Thanks. That error message appears to have nothing to do with that at first glance.